# How to change default float options for figures?

Tags: floats, positioning

I would like to change the default float options for my figures, so that I only need to adjust one option in order to change the behavior of all figures in the document.  On my previous computer (Ubuntu 14.04), I had been doing something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\defaultplacement}{htb}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[\defaultplacement]
\caption{Example}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

I'm now trying to build on Ubuntu 16.04, and am getting the following error:

```
./figures/ch1/coordinate_system.tex:1: LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `\'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 \begin{figure}[\defaultplacement]
```

It seems that previously, LaTeX was replacing `\defaultplacement` with its value before processing, but now it is processing the macro in place.  My guess is that my original solution was a bit of a hack, and that there is a better way to reset the default `figure` (and `table`?) placement that I've just been unable to find.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

LaTeX uses the contents of macro `\fps@<float>` as the default parameters for the float type `<float>`. It can be redefined, e.g. for `figure`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\fps@figure}{htb}
\makeatother
```

Then, the options of the macro applies, if the float is used without the optional argument:

```
\begin{figure}
...
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you!  For anyone who, like me, was mystified by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, here's a helpful question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do#8353

Answer (score 12):

Heiko's already shown the correct declaration, but to answer

> It seems that previously, LaTeX was replacing `\defaultplacement` with its value before processing, but now it is processing the macro in place.

No. Previously, unknown characters were silently ignored, so

```
[\defaultplacement]
```

was same as

`[\ d e f a u l`**`t p`**`l a c e m e n t]`

which, after ignoring unknown and duplicate options, was same as

```
[tp]
```

Incidentally, are you sure you want a default of `htb` ?

Disallowing `p` (float pages) massively increases the chance that all floats go to the end of the document.

Comment: I'm continually astounded by the intricacy of my own bugs.  Thanks very much for pointing this out--while I've accepted @Heiko Oberdiek's answer because it most directly addresses the question I posed, yours no doubt has saved me from a quagmire down the line.  Have a lovely day!